# How to build seperatorBuilder before itemBuilder in listview.seperated

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm trying to implement a chat screen in my app and I want to display the dates before the conversation ( [today, yesterday in most chatting apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWcgt.png) ).
To display messages I use the `itemBuilder` and to show these dates I used `seperatorBuilder` of `Listview.seperated`.
The problem is that the date widget appears after the message, which was supposed to indicate the date.
([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUZ7o.png), the 'yesterday' widget was supposed to come above the 'hey' message). (the `seperatorBuilder` builds after `itemBuilder`)

I thought to switch the codes of `seperatorBuilder` and `itemBuilder` (build the chat bubble in seperatorbuilder and dater widget in itemBuilder) to get the build order I want but I doubt its performance.

CODE:

```
ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index == 0 ||
                  compareDate(
                      currentSnap: snapshot.data!.docs[index] //snapshot from StreamBuilder
                          .data()['serverTimeStamp'],
                      previousSnap: snapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]
                          .data()['serverTimeStamp'])) // some checks before displaying 
                {return chatDater(); // the Widget that displays date container
              } else {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 0,
                  height: 0,
                );
              }
            },
            controller: _controller1,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index)
              return MessageBubble(
                timestamp:
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['serverTimeStamp'],
                message: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['message'],
                IsYou: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['sender'] ==
                        widget.usernameOfFriend
                    ? false
                    : true,
              );
            },
          )
```

the `compareDate` method:
checks if two consecutive messages have different dates, if yes then returns true (so that we can display the dater widget)

```
bool compareDate(
  {required Timestamp currentSnap, required Timestamp previousSnap}) {
  var currentDate = currentSnap.toDate();
  var previousDate = previousSnap.toDate();

  if (currentDate.year != previousDate.year) return true;
  if (currentDate.month != previousDate.month) return true;
  if (currentDate.day != previousDate.day) return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post compareDate() method?

Comment: Please check the question again now  .

Comment: Have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list. It's build on top of ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add timestamp also in `itemBuilder` when needed. Here is the simplified version:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: messages.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      final previous = index > 0 ? messages[index - 1] : null;
      final current = messages[index];
      final date = showDate(current, previous);
      return Column(
        children: [
          if (date != null) 
            Text(date.toString()),
          Text(current.text),
        ]
      );
    },
  );
}

String? showDate(Message current, Message? previous) {
  // TODO control when date is shown
  if (previous == null) {
    return current.date.toString(); 
  } else {
    return null;
  } 
}
```